# How to use two methods in the Restful WebApi with HttpPost attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, routes

```
public class IncidentController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Incident")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<IncidentModel>> GetAsync([FromBody] IncidentQuery incidentQuery)
        {
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("ProblemRecord")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ProblemRecordModel>> GetAsync([FromBody] ProblemRecordQuery problemRecordQuery, ILog log)
        {
        }   
    }
```

I have multiple HttpPost methods to from the same controller and i defined the ActionName attribute and also added the routes.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "Incident",
routeTemplate: "api/incident",
defaults: new { controller = "Incident" });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ProblemRecord",
routeTemplate: "api/incident",
defaults: new { controller = "Incident" });
```

Still the Context class throws the exception. Can someone explain me how to get over this issue. I have two methods with same MethodName and HttpPost attribute.

New to Restful webservice. Please help

Comment: What is the reason that you think it's wise to name two methods that do completely different things both `GetAsync`?

Comment: Sure i can name them different and i agree with you but still it doesn't route to the appropriate api called from the client

Comment: But your `routeTemplate` is the same between `Incident` and `ProblemRecord`.  Why would you expect it to behave otherwise?

Comment: i see you mean i should change the method name and then define the action in route template. Correct me if i got it wrong

Comment: I'm not sure exactly -- I prefer always using `[Route("{url}")]` on the action methods themselves, but I believe if you at least use a different `routeTemplate` for each action, you'll be good.  i.e.  `/api/incident` and `/api/problemrecord` or some such.

Comment: Above conversation helped me clear my doubts